# Лучший способ хранить цены для операций

Tags: sql, реляционная-модель

Я делаю систему для учета продаж услуги. Услуга имеет разную длительность (например, 5, 10, 15 минут) и цену (например, 300, 450, 750). Я также храню записи об оплате услуги: дата, время цена услуги. (Упростил для более легкого понимания)

Если я буду хранить цены в отдельной таблице (`price_list`) и добавлять ссылку на них в таблицу с операциями (`operations`), то при изменении цены в `price_list` поменяются все цены в таблице `operations` и "отчет" по операциям будет некорректен.

Первая мысль была добавить колонку в `price_list` `is_actual`, чтобы применять к новым операциям айди актуальной записи с ценой и не терять стоимость предыдущих операций.

Также была мысль не привязываться к айдишнику из `price_list`, а вписывать стоимость статически в столбец `price` в таблице `operations`, но тогда я потеряю информацию о длительности услуги.

Эти подходы кажутся не лучшими из-за избыточности. Что можно придумать лучше в такой ситуации?

Comment: А зачем вам вообще нужна связь между `operations` и `price_list`? И как у вас меняется `price_list`, он привязан к конкретной версии цен, за какое-то число, например? Как вариант, можно не менять цены в `price_list`, а сделать версионирование - запись в `price_list` будет иметь не только `id`, но и, например, `version`, и в `operations` привязывать `price_list` по `id` и `version`, и цены не обновлять, а дописывать. В общем, нужно целиком расписать что и как у вас обновляется - и тогда станет понятнее, как лучше сделать.

Comment: @CrazyElf, в ```price_list``` будут храниться id, цена и длительность. Услуга всего одна, просто разбивается на разную длительность. Связь между ```operations``` и ```price_list``` нужна, чтобы не писать цену и длительность услуги напрямую в ```operations```, а подцеплять эти данные для отчета, избегая избыточности. Задался таким вопросом, потому что может потребоваться изменить цену или вообще ее удалить, но при описанном в начале вопроса подходе так сделать не получится.

Comment: Ещё как вариант можно не удалять цену при изменении, а добавлять новую, с новым `id`, короче, вариантов можно миллион придумать. Или, например, добавить к цене поле `dt`, для актуальной цены там будет `NULL`, а для исторических - дата, по которую эта цена действовала. В общем, есть масса вариантов. Или вообще две даты - начальная и конечная даты, в которые действовала данная цена.

Comment: @CrazyElf, вот с добавлением новых записей я и думал. Неактуальные цены отмечать в ```is_actual```, никак их не изменять и больше не использовать, добавлять новые записи, уже с актуальной ценой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно понимать, что записи об оплате услуг - это исторические данные, и в них нужно записывать ту цену, которая была фактически уплачена (она даже может не совпадать с ценой услуги на тот момент). При этом никто не мешает сделать ссылку на услугу для получения детальной информации о ней (тут, кстати, нужно учесть, что состав услуги тоже может меняться). "Первая мысль была добавить колонку в price_list is_actual" - это вполне рабочий вариант, тогда таблица с услугами будет хранить их историю. Модификацией этого варианта может быть использование исторических таблиц (temporal).

Comment: Да, как вариант так тоже хорошо. Прайс хранит текущие цены, операции хранят конкретную уплаченную цену.

Comment: @CrazyElf Ну так это совершенно обычное отношение шаблон-инстанс. Когда, в отличие от обычного 1:N, та часть данных из ведущей таблицы, которая может меняться во времени, копируется в зависимую.